# How to modify page title section showing below header on webpage

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm building a website using skt trekking free template using elementor, Issue I'm facing is whenever I create new page, it creates new `inner-banner-thumb` below header that is not getting detected by elementor or not seeing any opton in WP dashboard to customize it.
like in image below you can see below for contact us page below header there is a big box with Page title name.
[image]

what is shows on chrome dev tool in inspect for this section:

```
.inner-banner-thumb {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 300px;
    background-color: #122937;
}
<div class="inner-banner-thumb">
            
        <div class="banner-container"><h1>Contact</h1></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
```

What I'm looking for is , I need to keep this section but want to customize it like adding background image/image slider, changing text color, and I need to do it for all page separately.
so Is there any plugin or addons or any option in Wp or elementor.
I'm using elementor free version